# Processing a database query in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, promise, handlebars.js

I'm using Express and Handlebars to display a value set by the user and stored in the database.

Handlebars is set up to display the value "{{userMotto}}".
Express does the following:

```
function isUserAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
        res.render('index', {
            user: req.user
        });
    } else {
        currentUser = req.user.username;
        userMottoCaught = queryDatabase("motto", currentUser);
        next();
    }
}
```

I want it to set the value of "userMottoCaught" to whatever it finds in the database. The query itself is this:

```
function queryDatabase(dbCollection, dbUID) {
    this.dbCollection = dbCollection;
    this.dbUID = dbUID;

    return MongoClient.connectAsync(hiddenkeys.mongodbUri)
        .then(function(db) {
            return db.collection(dbCollection).findOneAsync({
                _id: dbUID
            });
        })
        .then(function(item) {
            console.log("Found: ");
            console.log(item);
            return dbQueryResult;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            //err
        });
}
```

The problem is that I cannot for the life of me get the dbQueryResult out and return it to function queryDatabase itself. Probably because it's being returned to a sub function right now instead of the main function, I think. I highly suspect this can be easily resolved but I'm just at a loss on how to fix this. I am using Bluebird here to see if I could solve this with promises, but I'm not sure this is the right route either. I've also looked into callbacks but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to apply either concept to my code to solve my problem.

Later on when I render the page I do this to render it on the page:

```
router.get('/', isUserAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    res.render('dashboard', {
        user: req.user,
        userMotto: userMottoCaught
    });
});
```

Currently this yields on the page: "Motto: [object Promise]", because I haven't returned the proper value to the main function.

Is there anyone out there with some wise words?

Cheers,

Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to make a callback here

```
function isUserAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
        res.render('index', {
            user: req.user
        });
    } else {
        currentUser = req.user.username;
        userMottoCaught = queryDatabase("motto", currentUser,function(err,data){
       userMottoCaught = data
       next();
       });
    }
}
```

and the definition of queryDatabase should look like

```
function queryDatabase(dbCollection, dbUID,cb) {
    this.dbCollection = dbCollection;
    this.dbUID = dbUID;

    return MongoClient.connectAsync(hiddenkeys.mongodbUri)
        .then(function(db) {
            return db.collection(dbCollection).findOneAsync({
                _id: dbUID
            });
        })
        .then(function(item) {
            console.log("Found: ");
            console.log(item);
            dbQueryResult = JSON.stringify(item.motto);
            cb(null,dbQueryResult)
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            //err
            cb(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: This works with one small change: I still have to define that dbQueryResult equals the "item". However, what happens when I would want to take out the "next();" argument from the userMottoCaught section because if to add another query there? If I move it down one line, and into the else field itself, it fails and displays: "[object Promise]" on the page.

Thanks already though :)